# How to convert NAD 83 coordinates to latitude and longitude with rgdal package?

Tags: r, mapping, projection, rgdal

I have coordinates, all of which should be located in DC, but I cannot figure out how to convert them from NAD 83 to latitude and longitude in R. I'm using the `spTransform()` function in the rgdal package and get an error about non-conformant data.

```
library(rgdal)
nad83_coords <- data.frame(x=c(396842.6, 397886.9, 398315.5, 398154.3, 398010.3), y=c(140887.1, 139847.0, 138743.9, 139534.5, 138697.3))
coordinates(nad83_coords) <- c('x', 'y')
proj4string(nad83_coords) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4269")
Error in `proj4string<-`(`*tmp*`, value = <S4 object of class "CRS">) : 
  Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data: 398315.5 140887.1
```

Other combinations of proj4strings yield the same error. I believe the error is because the coordinates are too large, but I'm not sure why that would be. The documentation for the coordinates is below:

> Values are in the Maryland State Plane meters NAD 83 map projection.

I'm very new to mapping and projections, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: The crowd at [GIS StackExchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) are all over this kind of transformation, FYI

Comment: Thanks. I can't keep track of all the StackExchange sites these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up espg:4269:

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4269/

and its a lat-long system. So your big numbers (which are metres) are way too big.

If you've got a shapefile anywhere with data in these coordinates then you might have a .prj file with it that will have the projection spec, otherwise you'll have to chase it on spatialreference.org:

http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=nad83+maryland&srtext=Search

There's assorted variations on NAD83, and there's also 'State plane' here and there. I'm not too sure precisely which is which. The epsg: codes are more standard, then there's a bunch of esri: codes. The sr-org: ones are user-supplied on the site.

The esri code looks closest enough to the text you gave. Lets try:

```
> proj4string(nad83_coords)=CRS("+init=esri:102285")
> spTransform(nad83_coords,CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
SpatialPoints:
             x        y
[1,] -77.03642 38.93586
[2,] -77.02437 38.92650
[3,] -77.01942 38.91656
[4,] -77.02128 38.92368
[5,] -77.02294 38.91614
```

Anywhere near DC? Actually, epsg:2804 and epsg:3559 give the same answers, and are probably more 'standard'...

Comment: Thanks, that's great. To be clear, esri:102285 is the Maryland State Plane for NAD 83 with units in meters, and epsg:4326 is the standard longitude/latitude coordinate system?

Comment: Yup, for some value of 'Standard' :) If you look it up http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/ it tells you its what you get from a GPS. There are other standard lat-longs based on other measurements of the flattening of the earth, or different zero meridians etc...

Comment: Thanks for the clear question! Reproducible example, you've done a bit of work yourself, you've given us the error message.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this for the following set of x and y: (1 2262720.70221,    616937.73307). I use proj4string(nad83_coords)=CRS("+init=esri:102271")
spTransform(nad83_coords,CRS("+init=epsg:3436")) but it returns wrong answer: 9256140.81716 2171112.70876